# is there any photoshop plugin that helps in web development by auto measuring stuff

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'd like to know if there is a plugin that writes down all the distances between a layer from its all four sides to all objects near to it, and then do this for all layers.  Or at least write down width and height of all layers into one layer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any plug-ins but you can pull layer dimensions with javascript. A developer I work with has a jsx set up to grab the dimensions, position, and name of each group in the sprite files I provide. He outputs the results directly to CSS. You could just send it to the a text file or whatever suits you.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen a plugin that does this, but I'm not sure this is something you should be doing in the first place. Implementations should support text resizing and assume that elements will change size as business requirements and functionality change.

Comment: So, you never set pixel values in your CSS? You don't believe in a grid-based approach?

Comment: @plainclothes - if you're using a grid system, you shouldn't need to be measuring the pixels in the first place. You just count the columns.

Comment: But if you're experimenting with your grid in comps, I can see how you might want to run a quick check on where you're at. It's not the way I work, but I can see how it might be useful for some. Kinda like Dreamweaver ;)

Comment: what i am suppose to lol...lets just 'suppose' i am building an app..and not a news column.

Comment: @plainclothes - surely, though, you could just use a semi-transparent grid layer and bind a show/hide layer action in Photoshop? Then you could just read off the column numbers rather than worry about measuring up all the pixels.

Comment: The point is, you are free to play now, measure later. That was the basis of my previous answer concerning a js-based solution.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't do exactly what you're after, but this plugin lets you set grids that will help with web layouts:

http://www.guideguide.me/

You could then snap to the grids, setting your layers etc to certain width/heights.

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is - specking plugin, [www.wuwacorp.com](http://www.wuwacorp.com) (paid)

> SpecKing lets you instantly measure any sizes, margins, and font properties in any PSD file. Your design specs can be ready in an instant, with just a few clicks.